# How to add image beside text in an option menu?

Tags: android, xml, android-optionsmenu

I want to know if there a solution  to add an image next to a text in the option menu in xml like the photo:
[image: ZArchives]

Comment: You should have to make custome view and handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by adding icon attribute to your menu item xml and setting show as action to never like that :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/favorite"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_24dp"
        android:title="@string/favorite"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_favorite"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

where the ic_favorite_24dp could be any image/vector asset icon drawable you like in your drawables folder.

check this [link](https://material.io/components/app-bars-top/android#regular-top-app-bar) and this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#xml) for more information

Comment: you're welcome and good luck in your app.